# How to run android application when it is not showing the error?

Tags: android

I am working on android project. When I am trying to execute that project it is displaying a dialog box showing 
[image]

But it is not showing where the error is. It is showing only the cross red mark on the project.

Comment: Hi all thanks for all your valuable responses....I found the solution....I have deleted the .keystore file and now I am able to run all my eclipse projects.

Answer (score 3):

Please try following,

Go to Project Menu & Select Clean option.

if this doesn't work then,

Go to Project Menu, Select Properties, 
       from the left tab  select Java Build Path & remove the library or edit their path, which shows "red" sign.

Comment: Hello Sweety, was it useful for you  ?

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion...I have cleaned the project but even then the same problem...please help me

Comment: Hi for the second option it is not showing the red mark....also not only one project ....when I am tryong to run all the other projects in my eclipse it is showing the same error......please help me.....

Comment: have you checked your JDK version ?

Answer (score 3):

Clean your project.. `( Project -> clean)`

Or

Just check Problem window `(Window -> Show View  -> Problems)` for whats the error in projects and resolve it... (Library issues..etc)

Answer (score 0):

First click `Project` in the title bar and then click the `Clean` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in eclipse, select views error logs, and problems to see the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can Clean your project

Go to Project on  top taskbar and  then cleanthe selected project and then rum it

```
Project-->Clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the problems tab and see what it says. There may be an error in your layout xml. Or your build path is not correct. Also try Clean/Build project.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with eclipse telling me errors on R.layout.name not liking the R and wanting me to import something I shouldn't have to. Like others said clean project. I'm assuming you saved and reopened eclipse but if not worth a try. Double checking for red markings on code wouldn't hurt. possibly over looked an error.